# Not able to mount disk partitions simultaniously after cloning by cat/dd command

Tags: mount, dd, disk, cat, clone

In my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS virtual machine(in azure), I had 2 data disks (/dev/sdc & /dev/sdd) connected.

I attached 2 disks to VM as per:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal#connect-to-the-linux-vm-to-mount-the-new-disk

I created 2 directories /sdc1 and /sdc2 in the root of VM.
however, I mounted only one partition of /dev/sdc, that is /dev/sdc1 to the directory /sdc1 and created some files in it.

Later I unmounted it and cloned the contents of the partition to /dev/sdd's first partition /dev/sdd1 using cat command:

```
cat /dev/sdc1 > /dev/sdd1
```

Once it was complete, when I tried to mount these disk partitions (/dev/sdc1 to directory /sdc1) and (/dev/sdd1 to directory /sdd1). Only the first mount was getting successful.
That is, mounting both the partitions to different directories simultaneously was not successful. To mount one partition, I had to unmount another.
Or else would result in:

> mount: /sdc1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
> missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Can somebody explain, what is causing this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Note: I tried whole steps using dd command too, but the issue was same. dd command used:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/sdd1 status=progress
```

VM disk info:

```
root@testvm:/# lsblk | grep "sd"
sda       8:0    0   30G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0 29.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0    4M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0    4G  0 disk 
└─sdb1    8:17   0    4G  0 part /mnt
sdc       8:32   0    1G  0 disk 
└─sdc1    8:33   0 1022M  0 part 
sdd       8:48   0    1G  0 disk 
└─sdd1    8:49   0 1022M  0 part
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to manage a partition and its cloned copy at the same time. If you want/need to use them side by side, you had better change the UUID of the file system in one of them. That way, the operating system has a chance to tell them apart. -- It is even worse to boot into a drive while its cloned copy is connected.

Comment: You should be able to look in the kernel log to see the underlying problem report (run `dmesg` for example)